# Thread creation inside cycle

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I' m trying to make a trivial program i have input from command line n int elemnts; after I make n threads with argument the number in i position; after this the *function print the number i put in the pthread_create.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
pthread_t * tid;
int i=0;        
int n;
int *pn = &n;

tid = (pthread_t *) malloc (sizeof(pthread_t)*(argc-1));                

for (i=1; i<argc; i++)  { //cycle 1
    *pn = atoi(argv[i]);
    pthread_create(tid+i, NULL, function, (void *) pn);
}   
for (i=0; i<argc-1; i++){
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}   
return 0;}


void *function(void * param){
      int *k = (int *) param;
    printf("i got this number: %d\n", *k);
    pthread_exit(0);
   }
```

I run and i get this:

```
./test 1 2 3 4
 i got this number: 3
 i got this number: 3
 i got this number: 4
 i got this number: 4
```

the output change always but i never get the correct numbers (4, 1, 2, 3) not only in this order, i know that i can't get the correct order (to do this i put the join inside cycle 1). Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends.

Comment: What if no arguments are passed? Always check the result of `malloc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each thread is getting passed the same pointer, so each one is looking at the same variable.  You end up in a race condition as a result.

You need to pass each thread its own variable:

```
int *n = malloc(argc * sizeof(int));
if (n == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
for (i=1; i<argc; i++)  { //cycle 1
    n[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
    pthread_create(tid+i, NULL, function, (void *) &n[i]);
}
```